# How can i update a mongoose array with express js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have the following document, its kind of a board the includes lists that includes tasks (like todo list)

```
{
    "boardMembers": [
        "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d",
    ],
    "boardLists": [
        {
            "cards": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f7c9b77eb751310a41319ab",
                    "text": "task one"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f7c9bb524dd8d42d469bba3",
                    "text": "task two"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5f7c9b6b02c19f21a493cb7d",
            "title": "List one",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5f63877177beba2e3c15d159",
    "boardName": "board1",
    "boardPassword": "123456",
    "boardCreator": "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d",
    "g_createdAt": "2020-09-17T15:57:37.616Z",
    "__v": 46
}
```

How can I update and delete one of those cards? (I dont have a task schema, I want to delete the task from the board document

I tried this:

```
router.put("/delete-task/:list/:task", auth, boardAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const listId = req.params.list;
  const task = req.params.task;

  const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: req.board._id });
  if (!board) return res.status(404).send("no such board");

  Board.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.board._id },
    { $pull: { "boardLists.$[outer].cards": { _id: task } } },
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ "outer._id": listId }],
    }
  );
  res.send(board);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filtered positional operator [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_%5B%3Cidentifier%3E%5D) which identifies the array elements that match the [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) for updates.

For updating an object in `cards` array:

```
Board.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "boardId" },
  { $set: { "boardLists.$[outer].cards.$[inner].text": "update value" } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "outer._id": "boardListId" },
      { "inner.text": "task two" },
    ]
  }
);
```

For removing an object in `cards` array use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
Board.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "boardId" },
  { $pull: { "boardLists.$[outer].cards": { text: "task two" } } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{ "outer._id": "boardListId" }],
  }
);
```

Comment: What the outer and inner means? And if i want to filter by id and not text

Comment: @Timo222 They are just positional identifier for the objects in the array `boardList` and `cards` i;e which object to refer to in these array (and also used to put filter on which object using `arrayFilters`) They could be given other name as well like: `boardLists.$[i].cards.$[j].text` . For simplicity I named them outer and inner.

Comment: @Timo222 And you can filter by id too or any other property.

Comment: @Timo222 If `task` at `{ _id: task }` and `listId` are incoming as strings, you may want to cast them as instance of `ObjectId`. Example: `{ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(task)}` and `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(listId)` and try that out.